# Adding elements to array

Tags: java, arrays

First off apologies if this is a simple question, but I am very stuck with it.

I need to create an array with a total number of elements, there is 14. I want to add each of the 14 elements to the array and was recommended doing this with a loop as I will be doing more tasks like this but with much more elements. I have tried this code so far but am having no luck;

```
int [] deviceID;
for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
{
    deviceID[i];
}
```

but I get the exception `insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression`. 
So then I changed the line to

```
deviceID = deviceID[i];
```

Now I get a `Type Mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]`

just to be clear I want slot 0 of the array have the value 292, slot 1 have 293........slot 14 have 305

Can anyone help me on this? What I thought would be basic and easy is turning into a bit of a nightmare for me.

Comment: what are you trying actually you want to add elements to array, but what data you want to add, here you are assigning array element to complete array object itself deviceId = deviceID[i] which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to initialize array `int[] deviceId = new int[20];`
2. I *guess* you want to add `292` to `305` in array.

---

```
int [] deviceID= new int[14];//total element 14 (index 0 to 13)
int j=0;//counter which provides index during loop
for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
{
   if(j<deviceID.length)//chech whether j<14 as we want to add upto index 13   
   deviceID[j++]=i;//store i to the array at index j 
   //increments j to provide next index
}
```

*I suggest you to read about [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) from [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) it will clear all your dobts and bring some extra energy in you to start coding again.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want to do, but if you want to have values from 292 to 305 in an array you should do:

```
int [] deviceID = new int[305];
for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
{
    deviceID[i] = i;
}
```

But it's really weird. What is your purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the array.

```
int[] deviceId = new int[sizeOfArray];
```

Where `sizeOfarray`, is an integer value indicating the size of the array.

Then to assign the position, you must use

```
deviceId[index] = value;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Are you saying he doesn't need to instantiate the array before using it?

Comment: (Not the downvoter but) `new deviceId[int val]` isn't correct. It should just be `new int[val]`

Comment: I modified it to be a bit better. But I think the answer has been arrived at, lot of silliness for such a simple question.

Comment: It's still got the `deviceId` rather than `int`. `deviceId` is just the variable name. It isn't the type. The complete line should be `int[] deviceId = new int[sizeOfArray];`

Comment: And that is often the case. I think I'm arrving late but I see debris from assorted disagreements on other answers

Comment: Oh wow, that's amazingly stupid. I was too busy looking at people causing array index out of bounds exceptions to notice that!

Comment: Fixed properly this time.. I deserved that downvote.

Comment: Much better. It is so easily done. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fill your integer array deviceID with those values of i, you'll need to first make sure the array is big enough, and then simply fill the array. Your problem was from trying to set your entire array equal to a single integer from one index (hence the type mismatch error).

```
int[] deviceID = new int[necessarySize]; // Creates an array with size "necessarySize"
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
{
    deviceID[counter] = i; // Fills the array at index "counter" with value "i"
    counter++;
}
```

If this is your entire array, then you'd only need (305-292)+1 = 14 spaces in your array.

Comment: This will cause an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get slot 0 int he array equal to 292, slot 1 = 293..... slot 14 = 305

Comment: Ah. The above should work (with the counter putting the values in the right spots). The indices of an array start at 0, so the indices would be 0-13 (for 14 spots, starting at 292 and ending at 305).

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII You need to keep in mind that the OP is a beginner so using something like `new deviceId[int val]` which is invalid will cetainly confuse the OP, then without a sample of where the OP should put what code is not helping. Also I haven't downvoted yet, but that was just rude

Comment: @user1066946 It was rude, as was the person down voting without explanation to a valid answer. The OP being a beginner shouldn't influence the validity of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**DO THIS**

```
 int[] deviceId = new int[14]; //this creates a new array with size 14

 int j=0; // for array index

 for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
 {

 deviceID[j] = i;      //this inserts value of i at array position j  

 j++;                  //this keeps on adding 1 to previous value     
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

deviceID[i] just gets the i'th element in deviceID and does nothing with it.

deviceID = deviceID[i] is trying to assign an int to an object declared as a list, hence your error.

What you want to do is:

```
    List<int> deviceID = new List<int>()
    for(int i = 292; i <= 305; i++)
    {
        deviceID.add(i);
    }
```

This should give you a list with only the numbers 292-305 in it

Comment: Collections cannot contain primitives, you'd need a wrapper class and you cannot instantiate an interface.

Comment: And, in Java List is an interface. So you should choose an implementation.